# Get the instance of CKEDITOR currently being edited

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have a page with several ckeditors. I would like to get it setup so that on keyup within a given editor the contents is saved to the database. I have tried a few options like:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    var content = CKEDITOR.instances[name].getData();
   //ajax call to save data
```

But obviously this doesn't work because the textarea is replaced by an iframe and a whole separate DOM inside that iframe.

The main question is how can I dynamically figure out which editor is being typed in?

I know I could constantly cycle between all the ckeditor instances w/ setInterval but there are close to 30 ckeditor instances and that would be a lot on the db. Is there something built into ckeditor I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 things that can help you:

- [`CKEDITOR.currentInstance`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-currentInstance) event - fired when the [`CKEDITOR.currentInstance`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-currentInstance) value changes. This property stores the currently focused editor.
- [`editor.focus`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-focus) and [`editor.blur`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-blur) events - you can also listen on the editor level whether it is focused or blurred and check the state at any moment using [`focusManager.hasFocus`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.focusManager-property-hasFocus).
- [`editor.change`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) event - if you are more interested on when something changes rather than which editor is focus, then this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work

```
$(function () {

    $('#yourid').ckeditor(editorConfig);

    CKEDITOR.instances.yourid.on('blur', callBackFunction);
});
```

the function callbackHandler will be called on blur event